# Выдает ошибку SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    print('Компьютер заблокирован. Вернёшь скейт — скажу код разблокировки!')
    cod=int(input('Введите код:'))
    if cod==0550:
        print('Код верный, завершаю работу...')
        break
```

решаю задачу по бесконечным циклам на питоне. По условию нужно чтобы цикл отправлял сообщение вернешь скейт и т.п. , а затем предлагал ввести пароль и если он равен 0550,то программа завершала свою работу и цикл останавливался

Answer (score 2):

Твоя ошибка в том что ты не можешь проверять число где первая цифра 0: `if cod==0550:` , так просто нельзя делать абсолютно нигде. Так что просто убери `int()`
и число 0550 возведи в скобки.

Вот так выглядит абсолютно исправный код:

```
while True:
    print('Компьютер заблокирован. Вернёшь скейт — скажу код разблокировки!')
    cod = input('Введите код:')
    if cod == "0550":
        print('Код верный, завершаю работу...')
        break
```

Comment: "так просто нельзя делать абсолютно нигде" - неправда, иногда можно

Comment: Если у вас возникает вопрос можно ли так делать где-нибудь, то 
"так просто нельзя делать абсолютно нигде" - верный ответ. :)

Comment: @andreymal где?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  ;)

Comment: @Alexalexeev ну например какое-нибудь `int(cod, 8) == 0o550` вполне нормально отработает (но не так, как нужно автору). А в python 2 и некоторых других языках и запись `0550` является вполне корректной

Comment: ты всё равно слит :D